# FastAPI Optional validator

Tags: python, web, fastapi

I write some API with `Student` model, for update it - I use another model `StudentUpdateIn`. On `Student` model I have validator ( gt = 15 ). But how I can apply this validator to `StudentUpdateIn` too?

I found way with using `@validator`, but I think it is not the way, that I should use on my code.

Originally was chosen incorrect pattern....

```
class StudentUpdateIn(BaseModel):
    first_name: Optional[str]
    last_name: Optional[str]
    age: Optional[int]
    group: Optional[str]

    @validator('age')
    def greater_than(cls, v):
        if not v > 15:
            raise ValueError("Age must be greater than 15")


class StudentIn(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = Field(..., max_length=30)
    last_name: str = Field(..., max_length=30)
    age: int = Field(..., gt=15)
    group: str = Field(..., max_length=10)
```

Comment: Is BaseModel something that you have defined?

Comment: @wgwz nope, it is from pydantic

Comment: You will probably want to make your own subclass of that then. Basically override the BaseModel with your own BaseModel for students.

Comment: How I can get rid of it? I want to have only 1 class for it? Wanna delete StudentUpdateIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no non-hacky way of doing it, but if you dont mind to have some introspection in code, here is the decorator which takes field names and internally mark pydantic fields as not required (optional):

```
import inspect

def optional(*fields):
    def dec(_cls):
        for field in fields:
            _cls.__fields__[field].required = False
        return _cls

    if fields and inspect.isclass(fields[0]) and issubclass(fields[0], BaseModel):
        cls = fields[0]
        fields = cls.__fields__
        return dec(cls)
    return dec
```

Now you can use it to and have single class:

```
# you can specify optional fields - @optional("age", "group")
@optional
class StudentIn(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = Field(..., max_length=30)
    last_name: str = Field(..., max_length=30)
    age: int = Field(..., gt=15)
    group: str = Field(..., max_length=10)
```

or with inheritance

```
@optional
class StudentUpdateIn(StudentIn):
    ...
```